# Adding to ObservableCollection throws InvalidOpException because of enumeration

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception, binding

The following code throws an `InvalidOperationException` when the first item is added to the `ObservableCollection`.

```
public class RadioPlaybackStatusViewModel : ViewModelBase, IRadioPlaybackStatusViewModel
{
    private readonly IObservableState _state;
    private readonly ObservableCollection<RadioViewItem> _radios = new ObservableCollection<RadioViewItem>();

    // there are two instances created for this viewmodel each for a seperate user control
    public RadioPlaybackStatusViewModel(IPlaybackController playbackController, PlaybackType playbackType, IObservableState state)
    {
        _state = state; 

        // initially the state is empty
        FillRadios();

        Radios = new CollectionView(_radios);

        // state is my model which gets updated when an event is received from the business layer above
        // the events are sychronized to the UI thread using SynchronizationContext.Send()
        // when my client is connected it receives the radio status
        state.RadioStatus.DictionaryChanged += HandleRadioStatusChanged;
    }

    public ICollectionView Radios { get; private set; }

    private void HandleRadioStatusChanged(object sender, UpdatableDictionaryChangedEventArgs<ushort, RadioStatus> e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            // other cases which do not get called
            case DataListChangedAction.Reset:
                FillRadios();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void FillRadios()
    {
        _radios.Clear();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, RadioStatus> radio in _state.GetRadios(PlaybackType.ToDataContract()))
        {
            RadioViewItem viewItem = ViewItemCreator.CreateFrom(radio);
            _radios.Add(viewItem); // exception is thrown here
        }
    }
}
```

This is my XAML and code-behind:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
     <converters:RadiosListViewIsExpandedHeaderConverter x:Key="RadiosListViewIsExpandedHeader" />
     <converters:RadioStatusToImageSourceConverter x:Key="RadioStatusToImageSource" />
     <converters:HzToKhzConverter x:Key="HzToKhz" />

     <DataTemplate x:Key="RadioCellTemplate">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,0,2,0">
           <Image RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"
               Stretch="Fill"
               Width="32"
               Height="32">
              <Image.Source>
                 <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RadioStatusToImageSource}">
                    <Binding Path="Mode" />
                    <Binding Path="Mode" />
                 </MultiBinding>
              </Image.Source>
           </Image>
           <TextBlock Name="NameTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Text="{Binding Name}" />
           <TextBlock Name="FrequencyTextBlock"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Text="{Binding Tx, Converter={StaticResource HzToKhz}}" />
        </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid Column="0" Row="0">
     <Label Content="{Binding PlaybackType, StringFormat={}{0} Broadcast Status}"></Label>
  </Grid>

  <Expander 
     Grid.Column="0" 
     Grid.Row="1" 
     Header="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsExpanded, Converter={StaticResource RadiosListViewIsExpandedHeader}}"
     IsExpanded="True">

     <ItemsControl x:Name="RadiosView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RadioCellTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Radios}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     </ItemsControl>
  </Expander>
</Grid>
```

The user control are created in the main window manually and then assigned to a grid:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AddRadioPlaybackStatusView(PlaybackType.Voice, 1, 0);
    AddRadioPlaybackStatusView(PlaybackType.Fax, 2, 0);
}

private void AddRadioPlaybackStatusView(PlaybackType playbackType, int column, int row)
{
    var view = new RadioPlaybackStatusView(playbackType);

    Grid.SetColumn(view, column);
    Grid.SetRow(view, row);

    StatusGrid.Children.Add(view);
}
```

The exception I get is the typical

```
InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

..with only one stack trace entry.

Is WPF accessing my list when I add the item? Why am I getting the exception?

Comment: I would highly recommend using 4 spaces as a tab, not 3.

Comment: Is it possible that _state.GetRadios(...) is enumerating over the _radios collection? It appears like so given the error.

Comment: sorry for the code formatting (i tried but it didnt work)
@Dtex: no, GetRadios does only enumerate a dictionary contained in the state class

Comment: ok, i think the problem lies within the state class

Comment: EDIT: i was wrong, the problem does not lie within the _state class, i just returned a new item instead of accessing the state class and the exception still occured

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
private void FillRadios()
{
    _radios.Clear();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, RadioStatus> radio in _state.GetRadios(PlaybackType.ToDataContract()))
    {
        RadioViewItem viewItem = ViewItemCreator.CreateFrom(radio);
        _radios.Add(viewItem); // exception is thrown here
    }
}
```

to this

```
private void FillRadios()
    {
        _radios = new ObservableCollection<RadioViewItem>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, RadioStatus> radio in _state.GetRadios(PlaybackType.ToDataContract()))
        {
            RadioViewItem viewItem = ViewItemCreator.CreateFrom(radio);
            _radios.Add(viewItem); // exception is thrown here
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is a "dirty" fix but i will try it until i find a better solution, thanks

Comment: @leozilla That's not a dirty fix. You are mistaken with the way Clear() work with `ObservableCollections`.

Comment: Ok, the phrase dirty was a little bit hard. I know clear does also reset the view but i dont like to create a new instance of the collection view class.